# Upload file, insert file path to MySQL and return back to the upload page with string in URL

Tags: php, mysql, file-upload

These days I am designing a File Uploading System.
I want to upload images to server and store the file path in MySQL database.
After save file path, user will be redirected back to the upload page with the user string `uid=1` in the URL

*upload.php*

```
<form action="<?php echo "upload_file.php?id=" . $cid ; ?>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="photo" id="photo">
        <table width="295" border="0" align="center">
          <tr>
            <td width="289">Photos</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td class="formdisplay"><label for="priestname"></label>
              <label for="photo"></label>
            <input type="file" name="file" id="file" /></td>

          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td class="formdisplay"><input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" /></td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </form>
```

`$cid` is a variable that retrieve user id from URL using `GET [upload.php?id=1]`

And help me to create *upload_file.php* file.

Comment: You want us to write entire file for you? http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp

Comment: If any of answers works be fair and accept it...If not, ask.

Answer (score 1):

First the `form` needs to have `enctype="multipart/form-data"`
Now in your case i would create another `hidden` input instead of using a variable in the action.

Below is a sample i'm using

```
//use this to get the extension of the file
function findexts ($filename) 
 { 
     $filename = strtolower($filename) ; 
     $exts = split("[/\\.]", $filename) ; 
     $n = count($exts)-1; 
     $exts = $exts[$n]; 
     return $exts; 
 } 
    $ext = findexts ($_FILES['photo']['name']) ;
    //create files name
    $player_id2 = $player_id.".";
    $imgforDB = $player_id2.$ext;
    //the directory which you want to store the file
    $target = "img/players/";
    $target = $target . $player_id2.$ext;
    if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['photo']['tmp_name'], $target))
        {           
            //Tells you if its all ok
            echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES['photo']['name']). " has been uploaded, and your information has been added to the directory";
            $sql2 = $mysqli->query("UPDATE  **** SET `player_img`='$imgforDB' WHERE ***'")
            or die(mysqli_error($mysqli));
            }
            else {
            //Gives and error if its not
            echo "Sorry, there was a problem uploading your file.";
     }
```

That's pretty much the whole idea. On the DB it will be store as something like `player12.jpg`

Comment: Not Working 
Deprecated: Function split() is deprecated in /home4/diocol/public_html/churchinfo/upload_file.php on line 6

Answer (score 1):

I hope my sample will help:

```
<? 
ob_start();
$uploaddir = 'path_to_file/';
$uploadfile = $uploaddir . basename($_FILES['file']['name']);
echo $uploadfile;
if (!move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile)) {
    echo "Upload error.\n";
} 

//Query to store path for eample with PDO
$q = $conn_xyz->prepare("insert into images (path) Values ('".$uploadfile."')");
$q->execute();
//Store $cid in hidden form element then it is post, else it will be GET
header("Location: upload_form.php?cid=".$_GET["cid"]);
?>
```

You have some mistake in our code :

```
<form action="<?php echo "upload_file.php?id=" . $cid ; ?>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="photo" id="photo">
            <table width="295" border="0" align="center">
              <tr>
                <td width="289">Photos</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td class="formdisplay"><label for="priestname"></label>
                  <label for="photo"></label>
                <input type="file" name="file" id="file" /></td>

              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td class="formdisplay"><input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" /></td>
              </tr>
            </table>
          </form>
```

The good code is:

```
<form action="<?php echo "process.php?cid=".$cid.""; ?>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="photo" id="photo">
        <table width="295" border="0" align="center">
          <tr>
            <td width="289">Photos</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td class="formdisplay"><label for="priestname"></label>
              <label for="photo"></label>
            <input type="file" name="file" id="file" /></td>

          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td class="formdisplay"><input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" /></td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </form>
```

See the first line at form you wrote id= not cid = and some quotes are missing.

Comment: I don't see any missing quotes. And you use a javascript to redirect back to the form? What?

Comment: Yes I review to fast, you are right. And yes i use Javascript for redirection, i have to say I am not a PHP professional, I'm a sysadmin :-)

Comment: You would rather set a `header()`.

Comment: Yes, but if I need any debug informations, or I have echo i will get warning : Warning: Cannot modify header information

Comment: It is a script to upload a file. There won't be any echos. If you debug your code, just comment the header (`//header(...);`) or put an `exit;` right after the debug output. But with your javascript approach, you're executing the php, sending the javascript back to the user and the browser is redirecting to the requested page. Very insufficient and unreliable.

Comment: But I changed my code to header, and added ob_start (output_buffering) to prevent Warning, but i think JS is lazyest solution :-)

Comment: In your header(), you will not put the cid in quotes.

Comment: Approved. You're welcome ;)

Comment: Not Working :(
Warning: move_uploaded_file(path_to_file/logo2.jpg) [function.move-uploaded-file]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home4/diocol/public_html/churchinfo/upload_file.php on line 6

Comment: It's not always as easy as copy and paste ... -_-

Comment: As i see, you have no idea abot code, so:

Create a directory named uploads_dir in your home directory (/home4/diocol/public_html/churchinfo/) do chmod 777 for it, and replace in php path_to_file with uploads_dir. it will be $uploaddir = 'uploads_dir/';